# pdf: Date1 in one field and date 2 in another field; both drop-down calendars. How to express: If date 2 <= date 1+395 days "active" else "Expired"

Tags: pdf, logic, formula

I am converting a form in Excel to fillable pdf. This form has three fields, two user-populated date fields in drop-down calendar format and one auto-populating field based on an if/then logic formula comparing the two date fields.

In Excel this looks like: =IF(D13<=A13+395),"ACTIVE","EXPIRED")
A13 = the coverage commencement date and D13 = the claim date. The 395 represents one-year coverage limit plus a 30-day grace period.

The coverage period is one year from the commencement date (A13).  We offer a 30-day grace period after the one year is up (395 total coverage period). So, if a claim is submitted (D13) that is within 395 days of the commencement date, the coverage is considered active. If the claim is submitted outside the 1 year and 30 days, the coverage is considered expired.

Searched the web and tried a number of formulas. Only one returned an answer but it was "NaN". I am not looking for a number. Most popular error message is "Syntax error: Missing; before statement (X) line (y).

Maybe the problem is properly identifying the data field in pdf.  In Excel it is simply the Column identifier and the Row identifier for each date. In pdf, I ASSUME, I use the field identifier (name) found in Properties. In Properties for Commence Date, the field is named "commence'.  When the document is in the form edit mode, it is shown as "commence_af_date"